# SimpleInjector.Integration.AspNetCore 3.3.0 throws error in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017, simple-injector

I have an existing .net project in a .net core solution and trying to run the build in Visual Studio 2017 but getting the following error. Upgrading the SimpleInjector.Integration.AspNetCore would resolve the issue but there are some dependencies and I can not upgrade at this moment.

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   RG003   TargetFrameworkName is not recognized as a PCL or package based framework. Specify NuSpecTfm instead of using 'auto'    NA.AspNetCore.BuildPack D:\Deploy\NA.BuildPack\src\NA.AspNetCore.BuildPack\EXEC 1   

Error   RG001   Only PCLs are supported by this tool. TargetFrameworkProfile or TargetFrameworkVersion is missing   NA.AspNetCore.BuildPack D:\Deploy\NA.BuildPack\src\NA.AspNetCore.BuildPack\EXEC 1   
Error   MSB3073 The command ""C:\Users\smamun\.nuget\packages\nuspec.referencegenerator\2.0.0-beta-bld14\build\portable-net45+win+wpa81+wp80+MonoAndroid10+xamarinios10+MonoTouch10\..\..\tools\RefGen.exe" generate-single -m ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2;" -t auto -n "D:\Deploy\NA.BuildPack\src\NA.AspNetCore.BuildPack\NA.AspNetCore.BuildPack.nuspec" -p "D:\Deploy\NA.BuildPack\src\NA.AspNetCore.BuildPack\NA.AspNetCore.BuildPack.csproj" -f "D:\Deploy\NA.BuildPack\src\NA.AspNetCore.BuildPack\bin\Release\net452\win7-x86\NA.AspNetCore.BuildPack.dll"" exited with code -1.  NA.AspNetCore.BuildPack C:\Users\smamun\.nuget\packages\nuspec.referencegenerator\2.0.0-beta-bld14\build\portable-net45+win+wpa81+wp80+MonoAndroid10+xamarinios10+MonoTouch10\NuSpec.ReferenceGenerator.targets 50
```

This issue in [Github](https://github.com/simpleinjector/SimpleInjector/issues/379) is exactly same/simialar. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried deinstalling your NuGet package and doing a fresh install instead ofcan upgrade?

Comment: And try installing the latest version of Simple Injector.

Comment: Reinstalling didn't work but getting latest version works. However, that's not the solution. I have some other dependencies on multiple production servers. I am pretty much sure more people would have similar issues.

Comment: Most people already migrated to v4. Older versions of the nuget packages referred to the beta of reference generator. That worked fine with VS2017 beta, but that is causing trouble with the RTM. We can't change existing NuGet packages unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for your two cents, cheers!